# How to find out which user ran "mvn clean deploy" command using the resulted/uploaded jar

Tags: java, maven

In our project, there were so many developers are working.  And the code will get published into central maven repo only by our Technical lead who uses mvn clean deploy command.

All the other developers should use mvn clean install command to build it in their local & test it.  We are suspecting that, some developers mistakenly using deploy command instead of install command.

Is it possible to find out which user ran "mvn clean deploy" command using the resulted/uploaded jar.  Is there any entry which will point the system name or userId from which the jar got uploaded ?

Comment: In nexus it is possible to find out the uploader only the uploads are secured with authentication.

Comment: It is an antipattern to push builds from your local development environment, because it allows you to push dirty code changes which were never committed to source control. No one should be able to do that, even the tech lead. Push as part of your CI, after your automated build. Use credentials that only the CI server knows, so that no developer can push because they don't have the credentials. Humans make mistakes.

Comment: To answer your question: almost certainly not, unless you're baking something into the artifact that might identify them, like a hostname. I presume you're not doing that

Answer (score 0):

The `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` text file usually contains a "Built-By" line with the name (OS login) of the user that ran the Maven command.
You can find it by opening the jar as a zip file.